Determinant of a Matrix with Entries $A_{ij} = \frac{1}{\max(i,j)}$
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
   1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \dots & \frac{1}{n} \\
   \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \dots & \frac{1}{n} \\
   \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \dots & \frac{1}{n} \\
   \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
   \frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{n} & \dots & \frac{1}{n}
   \end{pmatrix}$$
i have calculated for case n=2,3,4 and i have conjectured
$\det(A) = \frac{1}{n} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1} \right) = \frac{1}{n!^2}.$
but i am looking for a general concrete proof if possible
eidt: providing the calculation
$\frac{1}{n} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = \frac{1}{n} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k} \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k+1}  = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{n!^2}$

Putnam $;2014; A2$.

@CherryBlossom thanks for the input, apparently its min(i,j) but the matrix is super similar

For $i=1,...,n-1$, subtract row $i+1$ from row $i$. This gives you a lower triangular matrix with the following diagonal entries:
$$\frac 11-\frac 12,\quad\frac 12-\frac 13,\quad\frac 13-\frac 14,\quad\dots,\quad\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n},\quad \frac 1n.$$
Therefore, we get:
$$\det(A)=\left(\frac 11-\frac 12\right)\left(\frac 12-\frac 13\right)\cdots\left(\frac 1{n-1}-\frac 1n\right)\cdot\frac 1n.$$
Since $\frac 1k-\frac 1{k+1}=\frac1{k(k+1)}$, we get:
$$\det(A)=\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}\cdot\frac{1}{2\cdot 3}\cdots\frac{1}{(n-1)n}\cdot\frac 1n.$$
Each factor $k\in\{2,\dots,n\}$ appears precisely twice on the denominator, and therefore:
$$\det(A)=\frac{1}{n!^2}.$$

first of all this is not the answer, also i think 1/n can be extracted from the last column and thats the term u are missing here

@spiritedcaveman You are right, I was a little too fast. It should be fine now.

thats fine but i edited your answer for having faulty steps and i think you should rather approve the my edit and not bypass it by other method
